# PostgreSQL returning data as an array from a many to many relationship

Tags: node.js, arrays, string, postgresql, database-design

I am looking for the best way to store and retrieve an array of data. The solution I am currently implementing uses a many to many relationship as follows.

venue_themes

```
user_id  style  environment
A1A2     formal  indoor
A2B2     formal  outdoor
```

theme_setting_to_setting_enum

```
id  user_id  setting_enum_id
1   A1A2       1
2   A1A2       3 
3   A2B2       1 
4   A2B2       2
```

setting_enum

```
id  value
1   garden
2   beach
3   golf course
4   backyard
```

The query I currently have is:

```
SELECT vt.user_id, vt.style, vt.environment, se.value FROM venue_themes vt JOIN theme_settings_to_setting_enum ts ON vt.user_id = ts.user_id JOIN setting_enum se ON ts.setting_enum_id = se.id GROUP BY vt.user_id, ts.id, se.id;
```

This works but it returns multiple rows with the same data other than my setting enum values.

An example return is :

```
user_id    style    environment   value
AAAA       formal   indoor        beach
AAAA       formal   indoor        backyard
AAAA       formal   indoor        tent
```

This is fine but seems excessive if I have many values.  What I really want my data to look like is:

```
user_id    style    environment   value
AAAA       formal   indoor        beach, backyard, tent
```

Ideally I would have my values returned in an array or something similar so I don't have to build a function to manipulate the returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `se.id` from the `GROUP BY` clause, and use `STRING_AGG()` to generate the CSV string:

```
SELECT vt.user_id, vt.style, vt.environment, STRING_AGG(se.value, ', ') se_values
FROM venue_themes vt 
JOIN theme_settings_to_setting_enum ts ON vt.user_id = ts.user_id 
JOIN setting_enum se ON ts.setting_enum_id = se.id 
GROUP BY vt.user_id;
```

Assuming that `user_id` is the primary key of `venue_themes`, it is sufficient to have just this column in the `GROUP BY` clause (other columns of the table are fonctionnally dependent on the primary key).

You can control the order in which values are aggregated in the string with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
STRING_AGG(se.value, ', ' ORDER BY se.id) se_values
```

If you want an array instead of a CSV string, then use `ARRAY_AGG()`:

```
ARRAY_AGG(se.value, ', ' ORDER BY se.id) se_values
```

Comment: Thank you GMB.  Will this still be returned as a JSON object?